# The device, \Device\Ide\iaStor0, did not respond within the timeout period

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2008-r2

On my Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise system I have a bunch of hard drives. The disk mode is set to 'RAID' in bios and I have 2 disks set as RAID 1. I also have a couple of other disks without any raid to store other data.

On random occasions a certain drive (always the same one) disconnects with the following event entry:

> The device, \Device\Ide\iaStor0, did not respond within the timeout period

I have the latest Intel Rapid Storage software, I tried disabling LPM, switching cable, switching sata port but without any results. Does anyone have another suggestion for me?

Hardware:

- Motherboard: Asus P8H67-M PRO
- Disk: Samsung HD154UI

**EDIT**
Apparently this disk had a ATAPI standard instead of an ATA standard. So it might nog have supported all the AHCI functions. Enabling hotswap in the bios *DID* solve the problem (I think) but I have swapped the disk with an ATA one to get the system fully stable for sure.

Comment: More times than not, when I see this event it is somewhat rapidly (say a few months) followed with a `Server agents on SVR01 - Disk x failed` type email.

Comment: If it's always the same disk, that **really** smells of a disk going bad to me.

Comment: I would just like to add that in my case this was an early warning of a bad block on the disk.

Answer (score 3):

Try enabling hot plug in the bios for the drives.

"Asus H67/P67 owners: Asus has confirmed that hot-swapping should be set to enabled for most drive configurations, especially SSDs. Because of the number of issues reported using SSDs or newer model conventional drives the default setting will most likely be set to enabled in a future BIOS release across all platforms."

http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?87197-SOLVED-Vertex-3-Huge-Windows-freezes-due-to-iaStor0-device-problem

Comment: This worked for me (or appears to have so far) - MSI Z68A-GD55-G3 + Crucial C300 256 SSD

Answer (score 1):

I had excatly the same problem with my SSD.
The solution for my system was to disable Link power management (LPM) by settings these values in the registry:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\iaStor\Parameters\Port0]
"LPM"=dword:00000000
"LPMDSTATE"=dword:00000000
"DIPM"=dword:00000000 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\iaStor\Parameters\Port1]
"LPM"=dword:00000000
"LPMDSTATE"=dword:00000000
"DIPM"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\iaStor\Parameters\Port2]
"LPM"=dword:00000000
"LPMDSTATE"=dword:00000000
"DIPM"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\iaStor\Parameters\Port3]
"LPM"=dword:00000000
"LPMDSTATE"=dword:00000000
"DIPM"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\iaStor\Parameters\Port4]
"LPM"=dword:00000000
"LPMDSTATE"=dword:00000000
"DIPM"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\iaStor\Parameters\Port5]
"LPM"=dword:00000000
"LPMDSTATE"=dword:00000000
"DIPM"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: Are all 5 ports required, even if you have one?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but have you tried the registry fix

Click Start

Click Run

Type regedit

Click okay

Browse to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\services\iaStor

Rename Parameters to Parameters.old

Restart the computer

Comment: Already did that, without result.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to check:

Check the Intel RAID software console and see if it reports any errors with the drives and/or array.

Disconnect the drives and test them one at a time using the manufacturer's diagnostics utilities while not in RAID mode (or use another computer).

Start considering what else happens at the same time(s) the error is reported.

Comment: It's always the same disk that disconnects. And its not the raid array that has the problem. The only thing that the Intel tool says when it happens is that the drive is disconnected.

Comment: @Jens - These are three different things to try, not an ordered list. :)  Have you tested the individual drives?